# Rotate group of svg font letters and then move each letter x/y

Tags: svg

I am creating a web application that lets users play with fonts by rotating/resizing/moving some svg letters. Everything works fine till here.

I would also like to give users the ability to rotate all the letters at once around a common center (the center of the group), this is the problem because after i make this rotation if i try to move each letter separately it doesn't move vertically or horizontally anymore, it moves diagonally (depending on the amount of the group rotation).

Is there a way to rotate this group of letters and preserve the ability to move each one in the standard x/y axes?

Comment: I think ideally you will have to break it down into a bit of working code, like in a jsfiddle. Sounds like you will possibly want to look into matrices, and getCTM(), getScreenCTM() and account for the transformation thats in place (maybe with an inverse transformation?)

Comment: thanks for your answer @Ian, i put together a js fiddle to test: jsfiddle.net/fZssT/18 i removed all the non necessary code obviously so it is at its very minimum. in the definitive case the group should rotate around its center but most importantly the letters should move in the right direction after rotating the group

Comment: I think the only way to make this work is for each letter to be indepenent in its transforms. Groups would essentially be pseudo groups, where the user would actually be transforming each letter in what they perceive as a 'group'. Also, as Ian mentioned above, you should use matrix transfroms, with consolidate(), rather than transform strings. Is this suggestion possible for you?

Comment: i am trying to figure out how to use the functions wrote in the previous comments and hopefully will update this thread with good news soon, at the moment i have no idea even though i read almost all the documentation i could find about matrix transformations